# AWS SAM - Local Interactive Code Development

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-sam

I am transitioning our code to leverage more of AWS's serverless tooling for our data ops pipelines. I plan on using SAM to bundle up our applications. One bit that is tripping me up is how I can help the team develop on local in an interactive manner.  We will be mostly writing lambdas in python.

In prototyping our dev flows, I have a Docker container that matches the runtime of the lambda (the core of our system).  I know that we can locally invoke the function to test, but my issue centers on leveraging the code that will be packaged into the layer.

When developing interactively, I need the team to be able to import the modules that will be inside the layer, and eventually available to the lambda (in the same manner) at runtime.

One (very gross) way around this is to just copy our modules and keep them next to the handler, so I am looking for a path/process that:

- Keeps the layer building inside the SAM app
- keeps the modules that will be packaged into a custom layer available in a dev environment that supports local, interactive development.

To the last point above, I created the dev environment container as a POC, and the solution doesn't need to leverage that flow.  However, replicating/simulating the layer's runtime while allowing us to interactively build code and pull in custom modules is the core of the ask.

In short, does SAM or other tooling support local, interactive develoment?  Even if its a two step process (build) and create a runtime that exposes the modules from the custom layer, that would be great.